# Unable to install Play 2.0 Support - INTELIJ 12

Tags: linux, scala, plugins, intellij-idea, playframework

When I install(via plugin manager) Scala plugin support for Intelij 12 (required by Play 2.0 support plugin) i get following error:

[image]

Environment: Ubuntu 12.04 - x64

I would appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found direct sollution, but Intelij 13 + both plugins seems to work properly.